# Iterate though Backbone.js collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im working my way through a backbone web app (pretty new to backbone) and need some help on iterating through a collection as I fetch it. What I want to do is loop over each element in the collection and if the `progress` attribute is `100` show an imported `<div>`, else show a loading `<div>`.

I have this working for the last element in the collection as follows:

```
fileRepositoryCollection.fetch({

    success: function () {

        if (fileRepositoryCollection.at(fileRepositoryCollection.length - 1).get('progress') === 100) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#imported').show();
        } else {
            $('#loading').show();
            $('#imported').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't render html in a collection class. Your collection view should have a render method for rendering, defining how your collection looks in html. You then iterate trough the collection in a view.

Something like this:

```
var fileRepositoryCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function() {
        // collection rendering

        this.collection.each(function(file) {
           if (file.get('progress') === 100) {
                $('#loading' + file.get('some_id')).hide();
                $('#imported' + file.get('some_id')).show();
            } else {
                $('#loading' + file.get('some_id')).show();
                $('#imported' + file.get('some_id')).hide();
            }
        });

        return this;
    },
});

var repView = new fileRepositoryCollectionView({ collection: fileRepositoryCollection});
```

Comment: You can also seperate rendering for one element. Usually addOne method is created.

Comment: Thansks for that - i have brought the relevant code back up to the render method now, im using a table structure with an image being displayed depending on whether progress === 100 or is < 100, therefore i have to keep my two different images (imported and loading) in the one td element as follows: <td> <img src="css/images/imported.jpg" id="imported"></img> <img src="css/images/barLoader.gif" id="loading"></img></td> , unfortunately at present the code i have tried, and the code you suggested is only working with the last element in the collection now...